# Dynamic string clear using C

Tags: c, string

```
Structure {
   char* a;
   char* b;
   char* c;
   Tpye t; //Enum
}
void print() {
   list* res = CreateList(sizeof(Structure))
   string* buffer = CreateEmptyString();
   for(size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        strPushBack(buffer,'1');
        if(i==1) strPushBack(buffer,'2');
        else if(i==2) strPushBack(buffer,'3');
        Structure temp = (Structure){buffer->data,"0","0",num};
        printf("%s\n",buffer->data); //print correctly
        listPushBack(res,&temp);
        Structure *j = listAt(res,i);
        printf("%s\n",j->a); //print correctly
        strClear(buffer);
   }
   for(size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
       Structure *k = listAt(res,i);
       printf("%s\n",k->a); //just print an empty string
       printf("%s\n",k->b); //print correctly
       printf("%s\n",k->c); //print correctly
       printf("....\n");
   }
}
int main() {
   print();
   return 0;
}
```

`list` is a generic linked list with `void*`

`listAt` return with `void*`

In the second for loop `k->a` not printed correctly just print an empty string, `k->b` and `k->c` print correctly. If I move `strCleare` above `Structure *j...` the second print will not be executed well, just print an empty string. I assume that `strClear` function is not working properly, becuase I clear it.

```
string* CreateEmptyString() {
    string* s = malloc(sizeof(string));
    s->length = 0;
    s->allocated = 2;
    s->data = (char*)malloc(s->allocated+1);
    s->data[0] = '\0';
    return s;
}
void strClear(string* str) {
    str->data[0] = '\0';
    str->length = 0;
}
void strPushBack(string* str, char c) {
    if(str->allocated < str->length + 2) { // +1 c, +1 \0
        char* data = (char*)realloc(strGet(str),str->allocated*2);
        str->allocated = str->allocated*2;
        str->data = data;
    }
    str->length = str->length + 1;
    str->data[str->length-1] = c;
    str->data[str->length] = '\0';
}
```

I want to print everything correctly and I also want to use `strClear` function.

I know that this code code not makes any sense, this is a mixed part of my code that is not working properly.

In my real project I want to return return with `res` and I have to use `strClear` as well. `res` will contain about 20 `Structure`

**Edit:**

If I use do not use `string*` I use just `char*` everything works fine, thus I think `strClear` is not working properly.

The list: [list](https://github.com/k2masterpiece/stackoverflow/blob/main/list.c) I do not think that there is a problem here.

Other thing is that:

If I do not use `Structure`

```
void print() 
    list* res = CreateList(sizeof(char*));
    string* buffer = CreateEmptyString();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        strPushBack(buffer,'1');
        if(i==1) strPushBack(buffer,'2');
        else if(i==2) strPushBack(buffer,'3');
        listPushBack(res,buffer->data);
        printf("%s\n",buffer->data);
        strClear(buffer);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        char* t = listAt(res,i);
        printf("%s\n",t);
    }
}
```

This code will executed well.

Comment: `listPushBack(res,&temp);` looks suspicious because `temp` is only valid until the end of the current iteration of the `for` loop body in which it is defined. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: @IanAbbott that is good for sure. as I said if I move strCleare the above Structure *j the second print will print an empty string.

Comment: Yes, the `listPushBack` call looks OK, having seen the source to your list code.

Comment: @IanAbbott it is called before function exits so it is still valid.

Comment: @0___________ My original command was before the link to the list.c source was added, so I didn't know what the code was doing with `&temp`.

Comment: @IanAbbott it does not matter what code does. Whatever it is it is valid as the reference to the automatic variablre is used (even if it a call to another function) inside the function scope. So the source was not needed to know that

Comment: The last thing that is done on the `string* buffer` is a call to `strClear(buffer)`. All the `a` members of the three `Struct` data vales in the list are set to the `buffer->data` value, which will be pointing to a null-terminated, empty string by the time the code gets to the second `for` loop, so it will print an empty string for `k->a`. All three nodes refer to the same string `buffer->data`. Also, the code relies on the fact that `buffer->data` will not get reallocated by `realloc` after the first iteration of the first `for` loop, which is a bit dodgy.

Comment: @0___________ But I did not know that `listPushBack` was storing a copy of the data pointed to by its argument rather than storing the pointer argument itself. (If I was paying more attention, the size argument of `CreateList` would have been a clue that it might be storing a copy of the data.) If it was storing the pointer argument itself it would be storing a pointer that becomes invalid at the end of the loop iteration.

Comment: I have just edited my post and added some weird stuff.

Comment: The second version that calls `listPushBack(res,buffer->data);` is a bit of a red herring. The list was created with an element size of `sizeof(char*)` which is probably either 4 or 8, so `listPushBack` will allocate a node with 4 or 8 bytes of data and copy 4 or 8 bytes of data from `&buffer->data[0]` into the node. But is the memory allocated for `buffer->data` actually that long, or is it copying more than has been allocated?

Comment: @IanAbbott ahh okey, now I understand, I just think that is weird, now everything is clear for that part, but I still have no solution for my main question, unfortunately. I hope that someone can show me a solution.

Comment: Maybe you should be storing `string*` values in your `Structure` instead of `char*` values, and allocate separate `string`s for each `Structure` in the list.

Comment: @IanAbbott that is still not working, I get the same result. but I do not use strClear it works fine

Comment: `listAt` has a bug. It is always returning the data from the first element of the list.

Comment: @IanAbbott oh yes now I have to add ptr = ptr->next, I also edited the github. But the result is still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected version of `listAt`:

```
void* listAt(list* list, size_t index) {
    node* ptr = list->head;
    size_t i = 0;
    while(ptr != NULL) {
        if(i == index)
            return ptr->data;
        ++i;
        ptr = ptr->next; // this line was missing!
    }
}
```

Change `Structure` member `a` to `string*`:

```
typedef struct {
    string *a;
    char *b;
    char *c;
    Tpye t;
} Structure;
```

Then change `print` to allocate a new `string*` for each element, but do not call `strClear(buffer);` because it will empty the string contents:

```
void print(void) {
    list* res = CreateList(sizeof(Structure));
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        string* buffer = CreateEmptyString();
        strPushBack(buffer,'1');
        if(i==1) strPushBack(buffer,'2');
        else if(i==2) strPushBack(buffer,'3');
        Structure temp = (Structure){buffer,"0","0",num};
        //printf("%s\n",buffer->data); //print correctly
        listPushBack(res,&temp);
        //Structure *j = listAt(res,i);
        //printf("%s\n",j->a->data); //print correctly
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        Structure *k = listAt(res,i);
        printf("%s\n",k->a->data);
        printf("%s\n",k->b); //print correctly
        printf("%s\n",k->c); //print correctly
        printf("....\n");
    }
}
```

It will produce the following output when called:

```
1
0
0
....
12
0
0
....
13
0
0
....
```

Complete sources I used for the above demo:

**list.h**

```
#ifndef LIST_H__INCLUDED
#define LIST_H__INCLUDED

#include <stddef.h>


struct list;

typedef struct list list;

list* CreateList(size_t typeSize);
void* listAt(list* list, size_t index);
void listPushBack(list *list, void *val);

#endif
```

**list.c**

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"

struct node {
    void *data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};

struct list {
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
    size_t elementSize;
    size_t length;
};

typedef struct node node;

static node *nodeCreate(void *data, size_t typeSize) {
    node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->data = malloc(typeSize);
    memcpy(newNode->data, data, typeSize);
    newNode->prev = newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

list* CreateList(size_t typeSize) {
    list *list = malloc(sizeof(*list));
    list->head = list->tail = NULL;
    list->elementSize = typeSize;
    list->length = 0;
    return list;
}

void* listAt(list* list, size_t index) {
    node* ptr = list->head;
    size_t i = 0;
    while(ptr != NULL) {
        if(i == index)
            return ptr->data;
        ++i;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

void listPushBack(list *list, void *val) {
    node *newNode = nodeCreate(val, list->elementSize);
    list->length++;
    if (list->head == NULL) {
        list->head = newNode;
        list->tail = newNode;
    }
    else {
        list->tail->next = newNode;
        newNode->prev = list->tail;
        list->tail = newNode;
    }
}
```

**string.h**

```
#ifndef STRING_H__INCLUDED
#define STRING_H__INCLUDED

#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct {
    char *data;
    size_t allocated;
    size_t length;
} string;

string* CreateEmptyString(void);
void strClear(string* str);
void strPushBack(string* str, char c);

#endif
```

**string.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "string.h"

string* CreateEmptyString(void) {
    string* s = malloc(sizeof(string));
    s->length = 0;
    s->allocated = 2;
    s->data = (char*)malloc(s->allocated+1);
    s->data[0] = '\0';
    return s;
}

void strClear(string* str) {
    str->data[0] = '\0';
    str->length = 0;
}

static char *strGet(string* str)
{
        return str->data;
}

void strPushBack(string* str, char c) {
    if(str->allocated < str->length + 2) { // +1 c, +1 \0
        char* data = (char*)realloc(strGet(str),str->allocated*2);
        str->allocated = str->allocated*2;
        str->data = data;
    }
    str->length = str->length + 1;
    str->data[str->length-1] = c;
    str->data[str->length] = '\0';
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "list.h"
#include "string.h"

typedef enum {
    num
} Tpye;

typedef struct {
    string *a;
    char *b;
    char *c;
    Tpye t;
} Structure;

void print(void) {
    list* res = CreateList(sizeof(Structure));
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        string* buffer = CreateEmptyString();
        strPushBack(buffer,'1');
        if(i==1) strPushBack(buffer,'2');
        else if(i==2) strPushBack(buffer,'3');
        Structure temp = (Structure){buffer,"0","0",num};
        //printf("%s\n",buffer->data); //print correctly
        listPushBack(res,&temp);
        //Structure *j = listAt(res,i);
        //printf("%s\n",j->a->data); //print correctly
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        Structure *k = listAt(res,i);
        printf("%s\n",k->a->data);
        printf("%s\n",k->b); //print correctly
        printf("%s\n",k->c); //print correctly
        printf("....\n");
    }
}

int main() {
   print();
   return 0;
}
```